How to properly handle ProviderNotFoundException in flutter?
I use an MVVM architecture in my app using a simple (home-made) Provider (not the package Provider but the problem is the same) with a static Provider.of<T>(BuildContext context) method where T extands ChangeNotifier. All is working very well.
Now I would like to prevent bad usage of Provider by throwing a ProviderNotFoundException if Provider.of<T>(context) returns null, ie. if it is called without a corresponding ViewModel in the current context.
The case where Provider.of() throws an exception is never handled in the different exemples I found (on Medium, Google, Flutter Doc state management exemples...). In my case, I don't always want the app to crash and I would like to alert the user using an AlertDialog. The user can then stay on the main menu screen and try other pages.
I faced some problems and questions:

Using a simple try/catch block in the View is not satisfying: the try { } bloc has to be very huge to deliver the ViewModel to all the Widgets.
Isn't it bad to make the View responsible for this try/catch logic ?
The AlertDialog should no appear in the problematic View but in the main menu, but the main menu is not concerned by the Exception ; should I first catch the Exception in the View, then rethrow it, and recatch it in the Navigator or whatever ?

How to handle it properly ?
EDIT: as requested, here is some code:
My custom (very simple) provider:
class ViewModelProvider<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
    final T viewmodel;
    final Widget child;
    
    const ViewModelProvider({super.key, required this.viewmodel, required this.child});
    
    static T of<T extends ChangeNotifier>(BuildContext context) {
        ViewModelProvider<T>? provider = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ViewModelProvider<T>>();
        if(provider == null)
            throw ProviderNotFoundException('Exception in ViewModelProvider: no provider found with the valid signature ViewModelProvider<${T.toString()}>.');
        
        return provider.viewmodel;
    }
}
// And State<ViewModelProvider> to call dispose() when appropriate.

How it is used:
// Any parent widget:
class ExemplePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ViewModelProvider(
            viewmodel: ExempleViewModel(),
            child: const ExempleView()
        );
    }
}

// The view:
class ExempleView extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var viewmodel = ViewModelProvider.of<ExempleViewModel>(context);
        
        return ListenableBuilder(
            listenable: viewmodel,
            builder: (context, child) {
                // Widget tree
            }
        );
    }
}

